# Separate opening tag and closing in foreach() and if()

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having some problems with doing separate opening and closing tags, I get a parsing error, I done like this in mvc1-2 but how is this done in mvc4?

I'm doing a `foreach()` and depending on the count I'm gone open up a `div` and close a `div`

this is the code

```
 foreach (var d in Model.MenuDays)
 {
    if (d.Id == 1 || d.Id == 4)
    {
        <div class='row'>
    }

//code here

 @if (d.Id == 3)
 {
       </div>


    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it, I'm not sure

```
@{
    @:<div>
}
@if(true)
{
   @:</div>
}
```