# How to make If Statement inside foreach in ASP.Net view page in my case?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to display 4 columns in a single row. So after every 4 data there will be one opening `<div class="row">` and at the end closing `</div>`

```
@{
    int i = 1;
}
@{
    foreach (var item in ViewBag.Prod)
    {    
        if (i <= 4)
        {
            if (i == 1)
            {
                <div class="row mobile-bg-pic" id="sale-pic">  //OPENING div
                  }  

                    <div class="col-6 col-md-3 col-nopadding">
                        <div class="card" data-itmid="@item.ProductID">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="~/@(item.ImageLocation)/@(item.ImageName)" alt="Card image cap">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="card-title"><a>@item.Name</a></div>
                                <div class="card-text card-price">RM @item.Price <del class="without-offer-price"> RM @(item.FakePrice)</del><span class="discount">@(item.Discount)% offer</span></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    if (i == 1)
                    {
                </div>    //ENDING div
                i++;
            }
            else if (i <= 3)
            {
                i++;
            }
            if (i == 4)
            {
                i = 0;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

but it doesn't work as I expected it to. Actual rendered html code in the browser is below:

```
<div class="row mobile-bg-pic" id="sale-pic">
        }

            <div class="col-6 col-md-3 col-nopadding">
                    <div class="card" data-itmid="5ddc742f-df82-43d7-ab3d-073c7dfdb587">
                        <img class="card-img-top loading" src="~/Content/images/Batch17/22-D.jpg" alt="Card image cap" data-was-processed="true">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="card-title"><a>Diamond songket</a></div>
                            <div class="card-text card-price">US 45 <del class="without-offer-price"> RM 65</del><span class="discount">20% offer</span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        if (i == 1)
        {
            </div>
```

I see this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685943/separate-opening-tag-and-closing-in-foreach-and-if), But I don't understand. But this is the one I want

Comment: You must note that you only set to display the html when i == 1, that is where the problem is.

Comment: @MosiaThabo What are you trying to say

Comment: You have put your HTML within the if(i==1){ here } so it only runs when that statement is met.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could approach this. You must note that your loop for ensuring that only 4 records in `ViewBag.Prod` are printed must be dependent on how many records are available within that list.

So first Check How many records are within the list:

```
var RecordsCount = ViewBag.Prod.Count;
```

Now you know the number of records available, so 4 records must be printed as columns in a row. I am assuming that you may have a dynamic number of records:

So you could try:

```
int i = 0; //iterator for the records available
while(i < RecordsCount) 
{

   <div class="row mobile-bg-pic" id="sale-pic">  //OPENING div
    //iterator for 4 records interval
    for(int n = 0; n < 4; n++)
    {
       //Type your Html Column here, retrieve your list index using this notation:
       ViewBag.Prod[i+n]
      //Your must note that [i+n] keeps the value of i alive.
      //e.g when i = 0, then results for [0 + n] = 0, 1, 2, 3 - these are your index values
      //now for the second round, e.g when i = 4, indexes will be: [4 + n] = 4, 5, 6, 7
      //So you can use that to loop through the records in cycles of 4 items
    }
    </div>    //ENDING div

    //At this point, 4 records has been displayed
    //update the iterator
    i += 4;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want using the razor @helper syntax without changing your logic too much :

```
@{
    int i = 1;
}
@{
    foreach (var item in ViewBag.Prod)
    {
        if (i <= 4)
        {
            if (i == 1)
            {
                <div class="row mobile-bg-pic" id="sale-pic">
                    @DisplayItem(item)
                </div>
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                @DisplayItem(item)
                if (i <= 3)
                {
                    i++;
                }
            }
            if (i == 4)
            {
                i = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

@helper DisplayItem(dynamic item)
{
    <div class="col-6 col-md-3 col-nopadding">
        <div class="card" data-itmid="@item.ProductID">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="~/@(item.ImageLocation)/@(item.ImageName)" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="card-title"><a>@item.Name</a></div>
                <div class="card-text card-price">RM @item.Price <del class="without-offer-price"> RM @(item.FakePrice)</del><span class="discount">@(item.Discount)% offer</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```